# generics - dynamically using types

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `Column`, which describes the column of a SQL-like table:

```
public interface Column<S extends Schema<S>, T> {
    default String encode(final T value) {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

A column holds a certain type (integer, string, ...) and has a utility function to convert an instance of that type to a string (which is useful for logging purposes).

Next, I have a class `Schema` which describes the schema of a table:

```
public interface Schema<S extends Schema<S>> {
    List<Column<S, ?>> getColumns();
}
```

A schema holds a list of columns.

Let's create a concrete schema with just one column:

```
public static class MySchema implements Schema<MySchema> {
    public static final Column<MySchema, Integer> ID = new Column<MySchema, Integer>(){};

    @Override
    public List<Column<MySchema, ?>> getColumns() {
        return Collections.singletonList(ID);
    }
}
```

Next, I have a class `MyData` which contains data corresponding with a schema:

```
public static class MyData<S extends Schema<S>> {
    public <T> T get(final Column<S, T> column) {
        return (T) new Integer(164); // actual implementation left out
    }
}
```

Encoding the value of a column manually is pretty easy:

```
final MySchema s = new MySchema();
final MyData<MySchema> d = new MyData<>();

System.out.println("encoded identifier: " + MySchema.ID.encode(d.get(MySchema.ID)));
```

Now, let's try this dynamically:

```
for (final Column<MySchema, ?> column : s.getColumns()) {
    System.out.println("encoded identifier: " + column.encode(d.get(column)));
}
```

This doesn't work, since `d.get(column)` is inferred as `capture<?>`, which is not what `Column.encode()` accepts.

How can I solve this? I understand what is going wrong here (`Column.encode(T value)` only accepts a `T`, which we don't have right now), but I can't find a solution which does not loose the type-garanty we enforce by only accepting a `T`.

As a fiddle, here is complete code:

```
public class Test {
    public interface Column<S extends Schema<S>, T> {
        default String encode(final T value) {
            return value.toString();
        }
    }

    public interface Schema<S extends Schema<S>> {
        List<Column<S, ?>> getColumns();
    }

    public static class MyData<S extends Schema<S>> {
        public <T> T get(final Column<S, T> column) {
            return (T) new Integer(164); // actual implementation left out
        }
    }

    public static class MySchema implements Schema<MySchema> {
        public static final Column<MySchema, Integer> ID = new Column<MySchema, Integer>(){};

        @Override
        public List<Column<MySchema, ?>> getColumns() {
            return Collections.singletonList(ID);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String a[]) {
        final MySchema s = new MySchema();
        final MyData<MySchema> d = new MyData<>();

        System.out.println("encoded identifier: " + MySchema.ID.encode(d.get(MySchema.ID)));

        for (final Column<MySchema, ?> column : s.getColumns()) {
            System.out.println("encoded identifier: " + column.encode(d.get(column)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, without any context of what are you trying to achieve is very hard to suggest a solution, but from what I see there is an inconsistency in how the columns are declared, by the Definition Column<S extends Schema<S>, T> and how the columns are handled inside a Collection List<Column<MySchema, ?>>. In this case for the encode method I would say there is a missing encapsulation if the implementation could change for different types the implementation should use a class owned value and not expect it as parameter. In general the conversion from ? to a Type (T) requires casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a helper function with a generic parameter `T` which allows you to have a `Column<T>` instead of a `Column<?>`:

```
public static void main(final String a[]) {
    final MySchema s = new MySchema();
    final MyData<MySchema> d = new MyData<>();

    for (final Column<MySchema, ?> column : s.getColumns())
        encode(column, d);
}

private static <T> void encode(Column<T> column, MyData<MySchema> d) {
    System.out.println("encoded identifier: " + column.encode(d.get(column)));
}
```

Another possibility is to use the same *trick* and provide a convenience method `MyData.getEncoded`:

```
public static class MyData<S extends Schema<S>> {
    public <T> T get(final Column<S, T> column) {...}

    public <T> String getEncoded(final Column<S, T> column) {
         return column.encode(get(column));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. But also pretty awkward.

Comment: I created a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422084/java-generics-does-java-need-support-for-locally-defined-types

Comment: @JesterDaro The answer is not awkward, but the fact the Java does not allow to define generic parameters on a statement or block level as you noticed in your follow-up.

Comment: I forgot to accept, apologies for that. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: I find it awkward, because it makes the code bloated. That's it :). I did not mean to say that your answer on itself is awkward.

Comment: Yes, I think your intuition is right that a statement level generic parameter would be nice. Kocko gave an interesting comment in his answer to your other question that such parameters would have their own difficulties.