# Java generics - Does Java need support for locally defined types?

Tags: java, generics

I am hoping to reach the Java generics experts here. Let's say you have some typed class:

```
public interface SomeClass<T> {
    void doSomething(final T t);
}
```

There is also a function which gets you an instance of `T` given an instance of `SomeClass<T>`:

```
public static class Retriever {
    public <T> T get(final SomeClass<T> c) {
        return null; // actual implementation left out
    }
}
```

Now let's say you have a collection of `SomeClass<?>` and a retriever:

```
final List<SomeClass<?>> myClasses   = null; // actual implementation left out
final Retriever          myRetriever = null; // actual implementation left out
```

We are not able to do the following:

```
for (final SomeClass<?> myClass : myClasses) {
    myClass.doSomething(myRetriever.get(myClass));
}
```

Now my question: does Java need support to be able to locally define a type? Something like:

```
<T> for (final SomeClass<T> myClass : myClasses) {
    myClass.doSomething(myRetriever.get(myClass));
}
```

Here, the type `T` is scoped to the for-loop. We are defining `T` to get rid of the wildcard `?`. That's it. The introduction of `T` should enable us to write the desired for loop as expressed above.

FWIW, the following code is a workaround. We are introducing a function, solely for the conversion of `?` to `T`.

```
for (final SomeClass<?> myClass : myClasses) {
    workAround(myRetriever, myClass);
}

public static <T> void workAround(final Retriever myRetriever, final SomeClass<T> myClass) {
    myClass.doSomething(myRetriever.get(myClass));
}
```

A locally defined user type might be a more elegant solution?

Comment: What you have is called a "capture helper" and is the canonical solution for this kind of situation.

Comment: @newacct Thanks for using the jargon (`capture helper`), this helped me to continue my research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my question: does Java need support to be able to locally define a type?

No. The minimal scope of a type-parameter is the method, i.e. in order to have the type `T` available for your for loop, you will have to either defined the enclosing method a generic or the enclosing class. For example:

```
<T> void method(List<SomeClass<T> myClasses) {
    for (final SomeClass<T> myClass : myClasses) {
        myClass.doSomething(myRetriever.get(myClass));
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, see my work around (which is equal to your code snippet). The question was: wouldn't it be better/more elegant to have a locally defined `T` instead of being forced to create a ad-hoc function? In my opinion, we are creating a `<T>` function due of the lack of support of local type definition.

Comment: I see. Probably would have been cool, but you should consider that is most likely impossible, because Generics in Java work with the so called [bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) (added by the compiler and invoked at Runtime). Since it wouldn't be possible to have a bridge method for a locally defined type-parameter, that's why the scope of a type-parameter cannot be narrowed to local. :)

Comment: I see. I am pretty new to Java (and programming in general), so I do not have that much feeling with the specifics of the compiler and runtime process. My question seemed logical to me, but is indeed probably difficult  to implement. I more or less wanted to feel out what others think about this.